# how to remove editors icons from antd Image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

how to remove other editor icons like zoom, unzoom, rotate options from antd image.
while previewing the image from Antd Image.

[image: antd image preview showing other editor options]

Comment: Internally antd uses rc-imager package, i have checked it there is no prop based structure where we can hide it, for reference https://github.com/react-component/image/blob/master/src/Preview.tsx#L229, So as @Jkarttunen suggested try hiding with css, will post if any update on this

Comment: Or else you can use preview prop and try using your own model check the doc  https://ant.design/components/image/#previewType

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use CSS to hide the icons you don't want to see.

```
.ant-image-preview-operations-operation:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
}
```